# Why do Pop Rocks fizz longer in milk than in Sprite?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

After doing an experiment with Pop rocks in various liquids, it was noted that they fizzed the longest in milk. My daughter compared Sprite, apple juice, water and milk, and milk fizzed the longest. Why?

Comment: How much longer are we talking about here? If you can provide times from the experiment, that would be helpful.

Comment: There are a number of experimental factors which you haven't detailed. Did your daughter use same amount of pop rocks for volume of liquid? Was the temperature of the liquids the same? What was the experimental error in timing for each liquid? I assume no stirring. But I'm also unsure about the size distribution of the pop rocks. Could an abnormally large pop rock been with the milk? // Off the cuff I'd guess the milk was taken from the fridge and was much colder than the other fluids.

Comment: Likely the milk was a colder temperature than the other liquids, which will give a slower reaction hence lasting longest. Also milk contains a lot of stuff mixed in it, fats and proteins, so that may or may not cause the candy to be less soluble compared to water.